# How to read a file from blob storage to azure databricks with daily date in the file name

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to read Employee_detail_info file to azure databrikcs notebook from the blob storage container which contains other files also. The files will be loaded daily from source to blobstorage.

Employee_detail_Info_20220705000037
Customersdetais_info_20220625000038
allinvocie_details_20220620155736

Comment: Can you please confirm this: you want to read only`Employee_detail_info` files, but not the rest. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, I want to read only Employee_detail_Info_20220705000037 file

Comment: Are there multiple `employee_detail_info` files? If so, do they all have the same schema?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple employee_detail_info files(with daily date appended in filename)that come daily to the blob storage with the same schema and we have to process the latest one.

Comment: Can you also clarify this: So, you want to read only today's files that are `employee_detail_info` files? and all the files contain today's date in the filename?

Comment: Yes, I want to read only employee_detail_info file to databrikcs contains today's date and other files will processed  with other pipelines in ADF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Glob patterns** to achieve the requirement. The following is the demonstration of the same.

- The following are the list of files in my storage account.

```
Customersdetais_info_20220625000038.csv
Employee_detail_Info_20220705000037.csv
Employee_detail_Info_20220822000037.csv
Employee_detail_Info_20220822000054.csv
allinvocie_details_20220620155736.csv

#all employee files have same schema and 1 row each for demo
```

- Now, create a pattern for your `employee_details_info` type files. I have used `datetime` library to achieve this. Since every employee file has today's date as `yyyyMMdd`, I have created a pattern indicating the same.

```
from datetime import datetime

todays_date = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d")
print(todays_date) #20220822

file_name_pattern = "Employee_detail_Info_"+todays_date
print(file_name_pattern) #Employee_detail_Info_20220822
```

- Now you can use `Asterisk (*)` glob pattern to read all the files that  match our `file_name_pattern`.

```
df = spark.read.option("header",True).format("csv").load(f"/mnt/repro/{file_name_pattern}*.csv")
#you can specify,required file format and change the above accordingly.

df.show()
```

The following are the images of my output for reference.

- My files:
  [image]
- Output:
  [image]